# exception Json set lenient(true) i have exception with json

Tags: android, json, gson, response

I am developing an Android app that gets gson response from web services.

But, this exception appears:

> com.google.gson.stream.malformed json eception :use json reader.setlentient(true)
>    to accept malformed json at line 1 column 9

The web services send json as array of object
I don't know what is wrong.

This is my code:

```
 public class Clinci_info_frag extends Fragment{
      ListView lvcli;
      TextView clinct;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.clinic_info_frag, container,false);
        lvcli=(ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.ClinicinfoList);
        clinct = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.clinict);
        for (int i = 1 ; i<=30 ; i++){


            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
            String url = "http://lavendergroup.net/web_service/api/getClinicInfo?id="
                    + i;

            client.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onStart() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onStart();
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int arg0, String response) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onSuccess(arg0, response);
                    Gson gson = new Gson();


                    try {

                        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
                        JsonArray jArray = parser.parse(response)
                                .getAsJsonArray();

                        DataBasenewHelper  dbh = new DataBasenewHelper(getActivity());

                        for (JsonElement obj : jArray) {


                            Clinic_infoweb ido = gson.fromJson(obj,
                                    Clinic_infoweb.class);
                            Clinic_info cl = new Clinic_info();
                            cl.setId(ido.getId());
                            cl.setName(ido.getName());
                            cl.setInfo(ido.getInfo());
                            cl.setFrom_date(ido.getFrom_date());
                            cl.setTo_date(ido.getTo_date());

                     dbh.createClinic_info(cl);

                 ArrayList<Clinic_infoweb>   _listFromDataBase=dbh.getAllClinic_info();

                        ArrayList<String> data=new ArrayList<String>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < _listFromDataBase.size(); i++) {
                            Clinic_infoweb ci=_listFromDataBase.get(i);
                            data.add(ci.getId()+" "+ci.getName()+" "+ci.getFrom_date()+"  "+ ci.getTo_date()+" "+ci.getInfo());

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ci.getId() + ci.getName() + ci.getInfo(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                        ArrayAdapter<String> myadapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,data);
                        lvcli.setAdapter(myadapter);



                        lvcli.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                            @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                    int position, long arg3) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                int itemPosition = position;
                                String itemValue = (String) lvcli.getItemAtPosition(position);



                                     AlertDialog.Builder alert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                                           alert.setMessage(itemValue);
                                            alert.setCancelable(true);
                                            alert.create().show();

                                }


                            });



                        }



                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(),
                        //      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable arg0, String arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onFailure(arg0, arg1);
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "فشل تحديث جدول بيانات العيادات",
                    //      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onFinish();
                }
            });
        }




        return v;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Can you supply the definition for `Clinic_infoweb` please? You may have a simple error like a misspelt member variable name. Also on a separate note, I'd add a constructor for `Clinic_info` that took `Clinic_infoweb` as a parameter, rather than the current setting and getting.

Comment: Clinic_infoweb   is a class that have variables  int id ;   string name;